# Javascript selectively filter responses

Tags: javascript, forms, fetch

Suppose I have a pure-html form on a webpage, and I want to modify it so that if submits successfully, the page behaves the same way as before, but if the submission results in a 50x error, custom error handling logic on the client side is triggered instead of navigating to the error page. What is the best way to do this?

Submitting the form in the background via `fetch()` is relatively straightforward, and I can check the status code on the resulting `Response` object, but I can't find any good way to tell the browser to go ahead and navigate to that Response when it is good, i.e. pretend that the page submission had happened like normal. So far, the only solution I can think of is a ServiceWorker, but that seems like overkill.

To clarify, the goal is to have it behave in the same way as if there were no JS in the case where the server does not return an error, i.e. making a single post request, displaying the server response, etc.

Comment: Can't you just use window.location and go to Response.url . Though I'm not sure why you want to do this as you'd already have the response. Can you clarify exactly what it is you're trying to achieve in your situation? A 50x error doesn't seem correct for a form response either way.

Comment: Wouldn't setting window.location result in a _new_ http request? I want the browser to use the already received response body. Also of course, this is a post request with side effects, so you wouldn't want to submit the form twice anyway.

Comment: It wouldn’t result in a new post request as you’re just forwarding to a url but it would be a new http request. It sounds to me like you just want to replace the contents of the body with the response then if you don’t want another http request. But in your question you said you wanted to navigate to the response page, hence the window.location. I assumed the page you’re posting is different based on the wording there so a forwarding (GET) request would get you to the next page. Maybe draw a flow of the different page names to add to the question

Comment: Basically, the goal is to have it behave in the same way as if there were no JS in the case where the server does not return an error.

Comment: So what is the next page? Does your fetch request return JSON or html? If it’s html then just replace the body with the returned html. Otherwise you’re going to have to use window.location to move to the next page. I don’t know what the content is so not sure what else to advise. But if your creating something that has an ID etc that is returned in the response then your other option is to craft a new url and forward to that again using window.location. You ever need to use JS to replace the current content or forward.